# Flatten a list composed by objects or list without isintance

Tags: python

Having a list like:

```
l = [0, 1,[2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7], {1, 2}]
```

I can flatten it with:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
aux = []
for e in l:
   if not isinstance(e, Iterable):
       aux.append(e)
   else:
       aux.extend(e)
```

Is there a one-liner without type-checking to achieve this task?

Comment: Do you know about the inner elements.Are thoise always integers or could they e strings  or any thing? What about sets/tuples, do they need to be flattend as well? Could there be  more than one level of nesting?

Comment: could be any object. That's why I discriminate between iterable or not in the if check.

Comment: Why do you want a one-liner? The code seems pretty good to me

Comment: You can use duck-typing, e.g. try `iter(e)` or just try to loop over it, but why would you do that? And why do you want a one-liner? Why does the number of lines matter?

Comment: For only one nesting level you could do: `[x for sub in l for x in getattr(sub, "__iter__", lambda: [sub])()]` but that is sort of a pseudo type check. It will also flatten strings into their chars.

Comment: @DaniMesejo just to learn new techniques. And also, I try to avoid type-checking in my code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:-

[Pipe pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pipe/)

```py
from pipe import traverse
l = [0, 1,[2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7], {1, 2}]
aux=list(l | traverse)
```

#### Output:-

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
```

Comment: `traverse` is probably just doing the equivalent of the OP's code already...

Comment: I learned something new! And it works if there is deeper nesting.

Comment: @Bibhav how do you know this doesn't do type-checking?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep. [It pretty much does](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe/blob/66a60cbc12f63c0359fc25f3871c56f2bedde1a4/pipe.py#L288)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sure it does. It needs to discriminate between Iterable or not. I think this kind of "tricks" saves you time and energy in the long-term.

Comment: @user17189165 but you are explicitely asking for a way w/o type checking in your original question and then you're fine if the type check is done in some third party module? You could have just as well moved your original code to a different module then.

Comment: @MikeScotty  Yeah you made a good point. The question should have been "Is there a one-liner that frees me from writing type-checking code?" or somthing like that.